# How to find the starting address of text section of a DLL inside a process? (64 bit)

Tags: windows, x86, x86-64, windows-10

There was a question about this a year ago, but the answer doesn't explain how to do it in C/C++:

[How to find start of .text section?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18840/how-to-find-start-of-text-section)

I'm not talking about module start address, which we can get using GetModuleHandle(module)

I'm talking about the start of text section of a DLL inside a process, so when i inject a process (using dll injection) i can get the starting address of a target DLL and patch part of its instructions, basically i know the offset of a instruction inside the DLL's file on disk, and i just want to find the start of text section and add to it that offset so i can patch it by injecting into the process that loaded it

and the offset of that part inside the PE file is different from disk, for example in a test program that i checked the offset in disk was 0x300 and on memory was 0x1000 (32 bit app)

so how can i do this   that can work in both 32 bit and 64 bit apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots of [helper functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/) in dbghelp.h to fully parse the PE file

if you do not wish to use dbghelp.h almost all of these function has an Rtl Equivalent function in ntdll.dll which you can call dynamically (`LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddres`)

For example, the function [`ImageNtHeader`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-imagentheader) has an equivalent `RtlImageNtHeader` in ntdll.dll which you can use with `GetProcAddress()`

Below is a sample code that dump some pertinent details of all sections in a given module using dbghelp.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <dbghelp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "dbghelp.lib")
int main(void)
{
    HMODULE hMod = GetModuleHandleA("kernelbase.dll");
    if (hMod)
    {
        PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 NtHeader = ImageNtHeader(hMod);
        WORD NumSections = NtHeader->FileHeader.NumberOfSections;
        PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER Section = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(NtHeader);
        for (WORD i = 0; i < NumSections; i++)
        {
            printf("%-8s\t%x\t%x\t%x\n", Section->Name, Section->VirtualAddress,
                   Section->PointerToRawData, Section->SizeOfRawData);
            Section++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

compile and linked and executed

```
cl /Zi /W4 /nologo /analyze /EHsc /Od %1 /link /release

TextSectAddr.exe
======================================
Name            VA      Raw     Size
======================================
.text           1000    400     102600
.rdata          104000  102a00  155e00
.data           25a000  258800  1600
.pdata          25f000  259e00  e800
.didat          26e000  268600  800
.rsrc           26f000  268e00  600
.reloc          270000  269400  22400
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the text section of the desired dll, first you need its base address (DOS Header in other words) which leads you to its PE Header (using the `e_lfanew` field of `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`).

At the PE Header (or in it's structured name `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS`) you'll find a field named `FileHeader` that contain information regarding the number of sections exist in the desired image.

to get to the first section (again it has a structured name `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER`), you need to pass the DOS_HEADER, and NT_HEADERS by adding their size to the image's base address, and then you iterate through the sections checking it's Characteristics field for the values

```
IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE | IMAGE_SCN_MEM_EXECUTE
```

which indicates for code/text section.

When you reach the header of the text section, you can use the field

```
VirtualAddress
```

to get the start address of the code section

Think of it as this struct

```
 ___________________________
|                           |
|      IMAGE_DOS_HEADER     |
|___________________________|
|                           |
|     IMAGE_NT_HEADERS      | <-- Contains FileHeader which has the number of sections exist in the dll
|___________________________|
|                           |
|   IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER    |
|___________________________|
|                           |
|   IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER    |
|___________________________|
|                           |
|   IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER    |
|___________________________|
|                           |
|   IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER    |
|___________________________|
|                           |
|   IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER    |
|___________________________|
```

Comment: Hi @stylo and welcome tom RE.SE. Thanks for contributing on our site. Just as a remark, the inquirer was rather specific about needing some kind of API or C/C++ function rather than merely the description of how to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get PE image sections using [stylo's answer](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/22131/23069).
The following C code uses `fopen()`, `fread()` and `fseek()` functions.
So, this code can be use in any Unix-like systems.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return;

    FILE* file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (file == NULL)
        return;

    IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = { 0 };
    fread(&dosHeader, sizeof dosHeader, 1, file);
    fseek(file, dosHeader.e_lfanew, SEEK_SET);

    IMAGE_NT_HEADERS ntHeader = { 0 };
    fread(&ntHeader, sizeof ntHeader, 1, file);

    IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER secHeader = { 0 };

    for (int i = 0; i < ntHeader.FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
    {
        fread(&secHeader, sizeof secHeader, 1, file);
        printf("%-8s\t%x\t%x\t%x\n",
               secHeader.Name,
               secHeader.VirtualAddress,
               secHeader.PointerToRawData,
               secHeader.SizeOfRawData);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, what does the code do?

- [`fopen(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3.html) opens the file in binary mode.
- [`fread(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) reads `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` structure.
- [`fseek(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html) sets file position indicator for the `file` stream to the
  starting of `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` structure using `dosHeader.e_lfanew` value.
- [`fread(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) reads `IMAGE_NT_HEADERS` structure.
- Now reads all the section headers in a loop. Remember with `fread` the
  position indicator of the stream is advanced by the total amount of bytes read.
  So, no need to increment `secHeader`.