# How do I get the start address of the 'code section' and its size to know the end address?

Tags: c++, binary, address, section

I am trying to read the binary code in the text section of an executable game file (PE) programmatically but I don't know the start address and the end address of the text section.
I am using C++/Win32Api to do that mission.
Are there functions that can help me for that purpose?

Notice: I have searched a lot but I didn't find anything related to that.

Comment: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/29750/how-do-i-get-all-sections-in-a-pe-file-using-c/29754#29754

Comment: @blabb: Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to read the specification, and/or a tutorial, for the PE file format. There are many such resources; [here's one](https://github.com/libvmi/libvmi/blob/master/notes/pe.txt). Specifically, you're going to want to locate the `IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER` structures, and then consult their `VirtualAddress` and `SizeOfRawData` fields. You can identify the `.text` section either through the `Name` field, or by checking the `Characteristics` field for the `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE` bit.

Comment: Is there a win32-API function/s that does that on your behalf or I must do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I was post a answer in Stack Overflow, and this is the code:

```
HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("foo.dll");
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS NtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS)(hMod + ((PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)hMod)->e_lfanew);
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeaders = IMAGE_FIRST_SECTION(NtHeaders);
PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER codeSection2;
for (WORD SectionIndex = 0; SectionIndex < NtHeaders->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; SectionIndex++)
{
    PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER SectionHeader = &SectionHeaders[SectionIndex];
    if (SectionHeader->Characteristics & IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE){
        codeSection2 = SectionHeader;
        break;
    }
}
IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER codeSection = *codeSection2;
FreeLibrary(hMod);
```